# Need help with conditional formatting multiple ranges by minimum value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet that looks like this:

```
Column/Row | Value |
A1         |   1   |
A2         |   2   |
A3         |   3   |
A4         |   4   |
  Row with header  |
A6         |   5   |
A7         |   6   |
A8         |   7   |
A9         |   8   |
```

...

And this continues for multiple rows, same format, 4 consecutive values and 1 header.

I need to conditionally format the minimum value in each range to a specified color. So the first range (A1:A4), I want only A1 to be highlighted. I've tried doing this by choosing the custom formula option in the conditional formatting tab and typing in:

```
=min(A1:A4)
```

but this highlights all values A1 to A4 instead of just A1 and I don't understand why? Manually typing =min(A1:A4) in a cell indeed gives me 1, but I can't seem to get it to work in conditional formatting.

Once we have the conditional formatting down, would it be possible to apply the same formula to multiple ranges? As in, could I just enter my ranges separated by a comma like: A1:A4, A6:A9, ... and have just one conditional formatting rule/formula do this for me? Note that I don't need the minimum value in the entire A column, I need the minimum value in these specific ranges. Been stuck with this for a while, so I'd really appreciate some help.

EDIT: My question did not represent my actual data setup, I apologize for the inconvenience. This is my actual [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mM0M5040u9qYwRKNCYPUkJ4-7uTTcZ4YG7MoqzHInkw/edit?usp=sharing). Please help me highlight the minimum weights for each week. (B4:B10, B12:B18, B20:B26, and so on), ignore the other columns. You can view the formula creations sheet if you're interested in my attempts to do this. I have not granted editing rights with this link, but if you need them, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Click in cell A1.
2. Choose **Format > Conditional formatting** from the menu.
3. Change "Apply to range" from `A1` to `A:A`.
4. From the "Format cells if..." drop-down, choose the last option: "Custom formula is"
5. Enter this formula in the formula field that appears below that:

`=AND(A1<>"", MOD(ROW(A1),5)<>0, A1=MIN(OFFSET(A1,-1*MOD(ROW(A1)-1,5),0,4)))`

6. Choose your desired formatting in the "Formatting style" section.
7. Click "Done" and close the dialog window.

**How It Works**

`=AND(   ,   ,   )`

Three conditions must *all* be met for the conditional formatting to take effect.

`A1<>""`

First condition: the cell cannot be blank.

`MOD(ROW(A1),5)<>0`

Second condition: the cell's row number cannot be a multiple of 5. [`MOD` returns the remainder after a number is evenly divided by another number. So if `MOD(ROW(A1),5)` *is evenly divisible by 5*, there would be 0 left over.]

`A1=MIN(OFFSET(A1, ... ,0,4))`

This will check to see if each remaining cell is the MIN of a block of 4 cells around it.

`-1*MOD(ROW(A1)-1,5)`

This determines the starting point of each of those four-cell blocks. The second argument of `OFFSET` tells how many *rows* to offset. The `-1*` means we will always be wanting to move backward/up some number. That number will be the `MOD` of the ROW()-1 and 5. For the first cell in each four-block (beginning with row 1), this will result in moving back 0 rows (i.e., starting on that row). The second row in each four-block will move back 1, the third will move back 2, and the fourth will move back 3. From that starting point, `0` columns are offset and a block of `4` rows downward is grabbed. Because each row is moving backward by incremental steps, that block will always wind up on the *same row* (i.e., 1-0=1, 2-1=1, 3-2=1, 4-3=1).

Placing all that in the second argument of `OFFSET` and checking if each cell is the `MIN` in the four-block relative to each cell (which will wind up being the same block) will only format the value that is the `MIN` in that block (or, if there are two or more values that are equal and `MIN`, they will all be formatted).

**Important Note:**

If *any* of the details given in the original post are not true to the actual data setup, this formula will not work. It is specific to the layout presented in the post above.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer blew my mind. How on earth did you come up with that modulo logic? Unfortunately, it is as you have said. My actual data setup is not how I've specified in the question, and I've wrestled with your explanations to try and come up with my own formula but I still can't figure it out...I'll edit my original question and add my actual setup sheet, please help me once more and I'll accept your answer. Lastly, I'd love it if you could point me to some learning resources that would help me with logic building in google sheets :D

Comment: @AbdurRehmanKhan, I've sent two request for you to grant me editor permission to your sheet and have had your sheet up in a browser window since yesterday. Do you still need my help? If so, please check your email and grant permission today.

Comment: My apologies for the delay, I've granted you editor access. I absolutely still need your help.

Comment: I've updated your CF formula to this: =AND(B4<>"", MOD(ROW(B4)-3,8)<>0, B4=MIN(OFFSET(B4,-1*MOD(ROW(B4)-4,8),0,7)))

Comment: @AbdurRehmanKhan, please mark the original answer here as "Best Answer," so that others know that this issue has been resolved, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much @Erik, that's magnificent. I'll have to spend some time studying this new formula now. I'm truly grateful.

Comment: How did you come up with the MOD logic? How did you choose the number 8 specifically? Why did you subtract B4 by 3 and then by 4 inside OFFSET, can't wrap my head around that. If this technique has a name can you please tell me so I can google and learn about it?

Comment: @AbdurRehmanKhan, there is no name for this approach. I made it up. There really isn't any resource that can teach someone the logic and creativity necessary to solve problems. You can learn formula structures. But, by analogy, that is like going out and buying a bunch of expensive brushes and paints: you'd have the tools, but it wouldn't make anyone a real painter. As for how this works, I gave a full explanation in my posted reply. I'm not meaning to be impolite, but this is a volunteer-run site; so we can only do so much. The rest is up to posters to put the time in to learn.

Comment: I like your analogy and appreciate the time and effort you put in to help me. I didn't mean to come off as entitled. I just felt that your full explanation (while great) did not cover those questions, but it's okay. I'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: In case anyone else has the same question as me, you need to study and practice modular arithmetic theory + problems to fully understand how to use MOD logic to solve problems. I had never studied this before, so that's likely why I found it mind-boggling at the time.